# Someone scammed me, and I want my money back. What can I do?

Tags: fraud, chargeback

I was cheated by ebankbtc.com, which gave me this address: 1QiCsWaZxvNy4hXZMvQJEBcnVm5KH3fK5

You can see the transaction here: 
https://blockchain.info/tx/e22206dcf27249afa6576443b3953b11ae43c04050c9e663a64f61ea320a7a4f

So, I lost my own Bitcoin.

What can I do about it?

Comment: Welcome to the bitcoin stack exchange! I think we'll need a little bit more info to help you figure out what happened. You might also try contacting them directly (http://ebankbtc.com/contact.php) to see if they can help you figure out where your BTC is.

Comment: The transaction you reference doesn't seem to involve the address you gave. Can you provide more details?

Comment: @ChuckBatson Err, whoops. Sorry, that was my bad.

Answer (score 4):

If the receiving party is not co-operating you cannot enforce them to return the payment.

In this case it is recommended to take the case to your local police and make a  crime report of fraud. Most civilized countries have courts which can enforce the fraudster to repay the stolen property.

However getting anything back is unlikely if you were scammed in Internet. as most likely the culprint is in another country.

Welcome to non-regulated cryptoanarchy.